# Play in motorcycle chain - how much is ok?

Tags: honda, maintenance, motorcycle

Riding to day I could hear a rhythmic tapping sound. I occurs when I ease off the throttle. I *think* it is the chain tapping against the plastic chain guard when tension on the chain from accelerating is released.

I pulled over and was able to move the bottom section of the chain up and down between 2 - 2.5 inches. This seems a lot for me but I have read that bikes with a single shock absorber at the back have more play then dual shocks.

I have a 2000 Honda VTR250. Does anyone know if thats an acceptable amount of play and if not, whats the best way to remedy it (new chain)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule of thumb is about 1 to 1.5 inches of slack, so it does sound like yours is too loose.  Your bike manual will tell you exactly how to adjust it - there are many different ways, but generally there will be an adjuster screw on each side - make sure you turn them the same amount, and check your wheel is still aligned afterwards!

Comment: Most bikes have a measurement on the sticker on the swing arm too.  Remember different bikes measure it differently, my ducati tells me to measure it on the outside of the chain - i.e. the 1.5 inches should include the thickness of the chain at top and bottom, so really only around .75 of an inch play.